# What is the Laplace transform of $\frac{\Gamma(t,z)}{\Gamma(t)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, gamma-function

What is the Laplace transform of :
$$\frac{\Gamma(t,z)}{\Gamma(t)}$$
w.r.t. the real parameter $t$, Where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the incomplete gamma function, and $z\in \mathbb{C}$

EDIT

From this [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), we have :
$$\frac{\Gamma(t,z)}{\Gamma(t)}=1-z^{t}e^{-z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k}}{\Gamma(t+k+1)}$$
Thus, in order to obtain the Laplace transform, it suffices to compute :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{t}}{\Gamma(t+k+1)}e^{-st}dt$$